# does 'yutori' have kanji?

Tags: kanji

I mean the sense of the word used for education and lack of pressure in the job world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yutori 「ゆとり」 ( as in Sedai ゆとり世代 ) is always in Hiragana.

. . . and actually there's no Kanji for ゆとり that we can use today.

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1495343994
>
> - 明治期から昭和戦前期にかけての時代には、
>     ・「融通」 （二葉亭四迷ほか）
>     ・「余裕」 （近松秋江ほか）
>     などの宛て字（※と申しますよりは、熟字訓）表記が用いられておりましたが（※『日本国語大辞典』ほかより）、 ...........
> - 実は「饒舌」の「饒」という字に「ゆとり」という訓読みがあります。（漢字必携一級参照）実際には字義よりの訓読みといったところでしょうか。

<sub>does 'yutori' have kanji? -- I mean the sense of the word used for education and lack of pressure in the job world.</sub>

That's really well-put.  　　　　Compact. 　　　　 Haiku-like.

I can remember when  「ゆとり」  was such a positive word.